# Why does my struct become immutable in a method chain?

Tags: swift, struct, value-type

In Swift I am trying to implement a method "tap" similar to the method which exists in Ruby.

I've come up with the following example code:

```
private protocol Tap {
    mutating func tap(_ block: (inout Self) -> Void) -> Self
}

private extension Tap {
    mutating func tap(_ block: (inout Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        block(&self)
        return self
    }
}

extension Array: Tap {}

var a = Array(repeating: "Hello", count: 5)

a.tap {
    $0.append("5")
}.tap {
    $0.append("7")
}

print(a)  // (Expected) => ["Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "Hello", "5", "7"]
```

I'm not super familiar with mutating functions, inout parameters, or Swift in general, but the code above looks like it should work to me. `tap` works as expected when it's not being included in a method chain. When I include it as part of a method chain, like in the above example, the Swift compiler complains:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work? Can anyone provide a working solution and explain why that solution works?

### Edit:

Another example usage would be:

```
let user = User(fromId: someId).tap {
   $0.firstName = someFirstName
   $0.lastName = someLastName
}
```

`tap` is a convenience thing that comes from Ruby. I'm mainly interested in understanding why the types in my function aren't working out right.

Comment: Interesting question...I'm interested in hearing a full answer but here are some initial thoughts

While it appears to be working correctly, there may be some unintended consequences with some of the code. When you pass &self to the block, because it is a mutating function, it mutates the value of self according to the block. However, returning self also makes a separate copy of the array. 

So if you set b = a.tap {...}, 'a' will be mutated AND you will receive an independent copy of it in 'b'. It doesn't look like you're going for both, more just to mutate 'a' in place, right?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

According to this article, I don't think the desired behavior is possible for structs such as Array.

Answer (score 1):

The `return self` returns a copy of the original array, not the original array itself. Until this copy is stored as a `var`, it cannot be mutated. So, this would work:

```
var b = a.tap {
  $0.append("5")
}
b.tap {
  $0.append("7")
}
```

But not without storing `b` as a `var` first. Of course, you wouldn't create a `b` in the first place, you would just use `a` repeatedly as you already pointed out.

So, the issue is that you can accomplish `tap` once, but cannot chain `tap`s. This is because the return of `self` is implicitly immutable, and you cannot call a mutating function on an immutable value. Changing `tap` to a non-mutating function could get you what you want:

```
private extension Tap {
    func tap(_ block: (inout Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        let copy = self
        block(&copy)
        return copy
    }
}

var a = Array(repeating: "Hello", count: 5)

a = a.tap({$0.append("5")}).tap({$0.append("7")})
```

Because each invocation of `tap(` returns a copy of the original modified by the given block, you can call it on immutable types. That means that you can chain.

The only downside is that new `a =` in the beginning.